# Visual Studio - C programming

Tags: c, visual-studio, ide

Total NOOB here.
I've noticed that under Visual Studio common C commands are a bit different,
the only example I can think of right now is that VS insists on using scanf_s instead of scanf, but I'm sure there are other quirks.

what I'm asking is, should I be learning, or even working with C on VS and why?

Thanks

Comment: If you want to *learn C*, I would suggest to not use VS.

Comment: Microsoft doesn't really properly support the C standard.  Been nearly 20 years and still isn't C99 compliant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSVC does not **insist** but only issues warnings, to provoke you into using their own non-standard functions. The warning message from MSVC ***tells you*** what to do:

> *warning C4996: 'scanf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using scanf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use 
>   _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS*

which means putting `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` before any `#include` files.

I put the following lines before any `#include`

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE  
#define _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES

#include <stdio.h>      // etcetera
```

Anyway MSVC does not comply with C standards.

Comment: VS is missing some header files, but I am not aware of any legal C construct that VS can't compile. The fact that VS discourages the use of unsafe API's in the C standard library is a feature, not a bug.

Comment: @jwdonahue MSVC can't compile Variable Length Arrays (VLA) even when they were mandatory under C99, although optional in C11. I can't cite a source but my understanding is that MS influenced the standards committee to make the VLAs that they never implemented optional.

Comment: Ah yes, I knew that. Very annoying indeed. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: @jwdonahue some of MSVC's supposedly safer functions are no better, for example `scanf_s` family, which are even trickier to use than the originals.

Comment: True, but they are less likely to be exploited and that's the whole purpose of their push to dissuade folks from using them.

Comment: @jwdonahue the original `scanf` type functions can be used safely anyway, although this is not a recommendation to use them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170177/discussion-between-jwdonahue-and-weather-vane).